# SOHO wireless N router with PPTP VPN server support and gigabit

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

Are there any wireless N routers in the SOHO category that support PPTP VPN as a server (not pass through) and DDNS? If so, which ones are the most reliable?

I have a SnapGear SG300 router that is acting up. It was acting as my VPN server, DHCP server, DNS etc. I have a separate N WAP. I would like to replace my SnapGear (which was a great router) and the WAP with one device.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get an [N router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) that works with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).  This alternate firmware can be configured with a PPTP server.

Comment: That would probably work but I am looking for the "shrink wrap" solution if possible.

Comment: Looking around, I'm not sure if one exists.  You might be able to get a router with a PPTP server and another with wireless N to use *just* as an access point (turn off DHCP, connect to the LAN instead of WAN, and make sure to give it an appropriate address outside of your DHCP server.)

Comment: Just realized that it negates the "one device" aspect of your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt - Take a look at the Cisco RV110W.  It has an integrated PPTP server but comes with a limitation that I find pretty significant.  You must make your internal address range 10.x.x.1.  Check out [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/415125/setting-up-quickvpn-clients-with-a-cisco-small-office-router-and-getting-a-messa) post I recently did.